# How do I restrict the result of Sequelize Model.create to the properties of the model?

Tags: json, sequelize.js

I'm experimenting with Sequelize for the data layer in an API. For better or for worse, I have a table with over 30 columns but API users only need to know (to simplify this question) only 5 of them.

I built a Sequelize model that "exposes" just the fields API users need to know about (the rest are all nullable):

```
const Widget = sequelize.define("widget",
  {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    active: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN },
    created_at: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
    last_modified_at: { type: Sequelize.DATE },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);
```

I can use this model just fine in my service layer; in fact, my API endpoints to get a widget by id:

```
export default async function(widgetId: string): Promise<any> {
  return Widget.findOne({ where: { id: widgetId } });
}
```

and to search widgets:

```
export default async function(name: string): Promise<any> {
  const where: any = {};
  if (name) {
    where.name = name;
  }
  // More stuff here omitted for clarity, e.g., order and limit...
  return Widget.findAll({ where, order, limit });
}
```

both work lovely. Each returns a promise and when I jsonify the value from the resolved promise, the resulting widget contains ONLY the fields in the Sequelize model, exactly as I hoped for.

```
const widget = await getWidgetById(widgetId);  // works great (5 fields shown)
const widgets = await getWidgets(name);        // works great (5 fields in each search result)
```

HOWEVER, when *creating* widgets, the resulting widget JSON *contains all 30 fields*. This was not expected. The service layer invocation is just:

```
export default async function(payload: {}): Promise<any> {
  return Widget.create(payload);
}
```

and I called it from the API handler like this:

```
const widget = await createWidget(payload);
```

The JSONified widget has all 30 fields. I would like to restrict it to the desired 5 fields.

Now I did look into this but printing the value of widget after the `await` and I did see that Sequelize gave back:

```
widget {
  dataValues: 
   { id: 472304,
     name: 'ABC',
     active: true,
     created_at: 2018-02-04T04:58:31.812Z,
     last_modified_at: 2018-02-04T04:58:31.812Z,
     ======>>>>>> ZILLIONS OF OTHER FIELDS ALL NULL <<<<<<====== },
  _previousDataValues: 
   { name: 'ABC',
     active: true,
     created_at: 2018-02-04T04:58:31.812Z,
     last_modified_at: 2018-02-04T04:58:31.812Z,
     id: 472304 },   <<<<<<====== THIS IS PROMISING
  _changed: 
   { name: false,
     active: false,
     created_at: false,
     last_modified_at: false,
     id: false },
  _modelOptions: 
   { ... },
  _options: 
   { ... },
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

so there is some indication in there that Sequelize knows that what is in the model is only part of the table. When I pass that very object to `JSON.stringify` I get only the part in the `dataValues` section, so what I am seeing is some interesting magic with Sequelize's `toString`.

Digging deep into that object feels wrong to me.

Is there a (proper) way to restrict the "returned" (I know it is in a promise) object from Model.create to be restricted to just those properties in the model?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not possible. You can specify which fields can be created by adding a `fields` array in the options object: `Widget.create({}, {fields: ['name', 'id']})`. However, even this will return all column as dataValues. I also went through the create docs but see no mention of the feature that would accomplish what you're looking for (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create)

Comment: Darn, then we filter client side.... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. If you are looking to exclude some of the attributes when returning. You can exclude some of your attributes in `attributes.exclude` as an array.

```
Widget.findAll({
  where,
  order,
  limit,
  attributes: {
    include: [],
    exclude: []
  }
})
```